# Silly doubt on Vector Field notations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm really confused about some vector field notations.
I mean I know there is a deep connection between Vector space $R^{n}$ his dual, tangent space, tangent bundle and the whole concept of Vector Field.
But in order to study more advanced things I need to clarify basic points such as:

What's the precise "connection" between this notation: $\vec{A} (\vec{r})$ and this notation: $\vec{A} (P)$ (where $P = (x,y)$) and this notation: $F:R^{n} \to R^{n}$ $(x_{1},...,x_{n}) \in R^{n} \to F[f_{1}(x_{1},...,x_{n}) ,...,f_{n}(x_{1},...,x_{n}) ]\in R^{n}$ ?

Some simple example:

$\vec{F} (\vec{r}) = \frac{k}{\left\lVert \vec{r} \right\rVert ^2} \vec{r}
   $

$\vec{F} (P) = \vec{F} (x,y) = \frac{k}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}(x \vec{i}+y \vec{j})
     $

where $\vec{r} = \frac{\vec{r}}{\left\lVert \vec{r} \right\rVert}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection is a simple change of variables:
$$
r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \quad \vec{r}=\pmatrix{x\\y}
$$

When you express the field in terms of $x$ and $y$ you are in cartesian mode, and when you express it in terms of $r$ you are looking at it from a radial perspective.